# System Turning off, when power on? (Intel 101D MB, Intel Dual Core, Windows 7 32-bit)

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, shutdown, cmos

I Cleaned my system multiple times in past, today also i did the same thing. When i try to Power on my System, i am able to see the Intel Processor Boot screen(able to hear `Beap` sound) and after *1min it's suddenly turning off.* 
I checked my system all the way with in my knowledge, Like:
1. Resetting `BIOS` Settings (*jumper/comos* process).
2. Checking `RAM` by remvoing slots one by one (I have 2 slots **1+1 GB**).
3. And checking **SMPS** (*Green and Black* connection with wire, and it's working fine).

Is there any Check i am **Missing**?

Please inform me with Details..

Comment: What did you do when you cleaned your system? Did you disconnect anything? Did you remove anything?

Comment: Yes @DavidSchwartz, I removed CPU fan, RAM, IDE Card(DVD player), 24 power pin, SATA Cable and it's power pins. And i set it back again.(and verified).

Comment: 99% chance it was something you did during cleaning 1% chance something failed as a coincidence. Disconnect all but essential hardware (cpu and 1 stick ram) see if you get a post screen.

Answer (score 0):

There's a long list of things that could have gone wrong. For example, a hair or ball of dust could have lodged in one of the RAM slots. The CPU fan might have been connected to the wrong fan header. The heat sink may not be tight and flat against the CPU. And so on.

Comment: No luck @David Schwart, I again tried re-assembling my PC, same thing repeating. (system turning off afater 1/2mins, While pressing Power on button).